# Remove Image Number From Color box Slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

In Color box,

I want to remove the image number being displayed for images i.e. image 2 of 4 from the colorbox slideshow.How am I supposed to do that?. What am I supposed to change?

For Example by adding 
`display:none!important` in `colorbox.css` file is not solving my problem. I feel it can't be removed. But, we may have a solution in script programming..

So Far I have done as Follows:-

```
<a href="/img/slider/Bicycle.jpg" class="button1 button2" title="Image" ><img src="/img/slider/Bicycle.jpg"  alt="Feature-img" align="right" style="width:100%; height: 240px;"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the following property to your colorbox call:

`current: false`

And it won't show the current number of the image.

You can refer this in the documentation here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Thanks @drip , It saved me ..!